# Getting the first item of a split string list in a Pandas series

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook

If I need to split a string and get the first item, that's fine with:

```
string = "AAA_BBB"
string.split("_")[0]
> "AAA"
```

But if try to do the same with a Pandas series (given the series has the same string format), the `[0]` doesn't work.

```
df["string"].str.split("_")[0]
> KeyError: 0
```

But the part before the `[0]` works fine

```
1 [AAA, BBB]
2 [BBB, CCC]
3 [DDD, EEE]
4 [DDD, AAA]
5 [EEE, CCC]
```

I'm trying to do this to assign the first element to a new column like so:

```
df["new_column"] = df["string"].str.split("_")[0]
```

Comment: use the parameter `expand=True` in `split()`

Comment: use `str[0]` to get the first element. `df["string"].str.split("_").str[0]`